# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/auth/login/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I got error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://patrick-barbie-f64046e3bb4b.herokuapp.com/auth/login/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

POST https://myweb.herokuapp.com/auth/login/ net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

Here is my backend express

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({
   origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
   credentials: true,
   optionSuccessStatus:200
 }))
```

in my front end

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const baseURL = 'https://myweb.herokuapp.com/' + "auth"
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
})

api.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:3000';
api.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS';
api.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization';
```

I have tried to set cors credentials: true, and axios credentials: true, but it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the headers in client code? You should not have to do that normally.

Comment: Yes, I did try that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like below?

```html
let CorsObject = require('cors');
let CorsOptions ={
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    credentials:true,          
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(CorsObject(CorsOptions));
```

Comment: This do not work for me. I still got the same error.